"zsh: command not found: flutter" m2 pro silicon
I installed Android Studio on my computer to develop my flutter and dart project.

However, I downloaded the flutter folder for macos silicon from the flutter site and added it to a folder named "yusa".

I exported many file paths with the "nano .zshrc" command, but no matter what I do, when I type "flutter" or "flutter doctor" into the terminal, "zsh: command not found: flutter".

I get an error. My computer does not recognize flutter.
My problem has been going on for days and I need your help.
Thank you all in advance.

I solved the problem.
My .zshrc path was as follows:
ZSH_THEME="yusa"
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr$

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/yusa/development/flutter/bin"

I asked the AI ​​to edit it correctly for me. He suggested me to edit it like this and my problem was solved.
ZSH_THEME="yusa"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/Users/yusa/development/flutter/bin:$PATH"


I have had the same issue once. I ended up solving it by making a symlink to the /Users/myusername/flutter/bin/flutter in the binary directory. In your case:
ln -s /Users/yusa/flutter/bin/flutter /Users/yusa/bin/flutter
ln -s /Users/yusa/flutter/bin/dart /Users/yusa/bin/dart

It's far from perfect, but it works. Besides, the actual flutter/bin directory only contains two executables: flutter and dart.
Hope this helps!

Hello, thank you for replying. I followed your advice, but unfortunately my problem was not solved.

@herik06 That's unfortunate. I see you have homebrew installed. Have you tried using the homebrew version of flutter SDK: brew install --cask flutter?

I solved the problem. As you mentioned, there was a problem with the homebrew configuration. I fixed it. I will write the solution below. Thank you for your interest...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
